# std::coroutine_handle<Promise>::done() returning unexpected value

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++-coroutine

I am trying to write a simple round-robin scheduler for coroutines. My simplified code is the following:

```
Generator<uint64_t> Counter(uint64_t i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    co_yield i;
  }
}

...

void RunSimple(uint64_t num_coroutines) {
  std::vector<std::pair<uint64_t, Generator<uint64_t>>> gens;
  for (uint64_t i = 0; i < num_coroutines; i++) {
    // Storing coroutines into a vector is safe because we implemented the move
    // constructor and move assigment operator for Generator.
    gens.push_back({i, Counter(i)});
  }
  // This is a simple round-robin scheduler for coroutines.
  while (true) {
    for (auto it = gens.begin(); it != gens.end();) {
      uint64_t i = it->first;
      Generator<uint64_t>& gen = it->second;
      if (gen) {
        printf("Coroutine %lu: %lu.\n", i, gen());
        it++;
      } else {
        // `gen` has finished, so remove its pair from the vector.
        it = gens.erase(it);
      }
    }
    // Once all of the coroutines have finished, break.
    if (gens.empty()) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `RunSimple(/*num_coroutines=*/4)`, I get the following output:

```
Coroutine 0: 0.
Coroutine 1: 1.
Coroutine 2: 2.
Coroutine 3: 3.
Coroutine 0: 0.
Coroutine 1: 1.
Coroutine 2: 2.
Coroutine 3: 3.
Coroutine 1: 1.
Coroutine 3: 3.
Coroutine 3: 3.
```

The last three lines of the output are unexpected... coroutines 1 and 3 do not seem to be exiting when I expect them to. Upon further investigation, this is happening because `std::coroutine_handle<Promise>::done()` is returning false for both of these coroutines. Do you know why this method is returning false... am I doing something wrong?

---

Edit: Here is my `Generator` implementation:

```
template <typename T>
struct Generator {
  struct promise_type;
  using handle_type = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>;

  struct promise_type {
    T value_;
    std::exception_ptr exception_;

    Generator get_return_object() {
      return Generator(handle_type::from_promise(*this));
    }
    std::suspend_always initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void unhandled_exception() { exception_ = std::current_exception(); }
    template <std::convertible_to<T> From>  // C++20 concept
    std::suspend_always yield_value(From&& from) {
      value_ = std::forward<From>(from);
      return {};
    }
    void return_void() {}
  };

  handle_type h_;

  Generator(handle_type h) : h_(h) {
  }
  Generator(Generator&& g) : h_(std::move(g.h_)) { g.h_ = nullptr; }
  ~Generator() {
    if (h_) {
      h_.destroy();
    }
  }

  Generator& operator=(Generator&& g) {
    h_ = std::move(g.h_);
    g.h_ = nullptr;
    return *this;
  }
  explicit operator bool() {
    fill();
    return !h_.done();
  }
  T operator()() {
    fill();
    full_ = false;
    return std::move(h_.promise().value_);
  }

 private:
  bool full_ = false;

  void fill() {
    if (!full_) {
      h_();
      if (h_.promise().exception_)
        std::rethrow_exception(h_.promise().exception_);
      full_ = true;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: The issue looks like it might be with `it.erase()`, something must be getting copied or moved incorrectly. What happens if you use pointers to the pair instead of the pair?

Comment: Can we see your `Generator`? Does it suspend in it's `final_suspend`?

Comment: @ATOMP Yep I think you're right. The problem goes away when I wrap the Generator instances in unique_ptrs. I edited my post with my Generator implementation, which includes my move constructor and move assignment operator.

Comment: @FatihBAKIR I just added my Generator implementation to the original post. Thanks.

Comment: @JackHumphries using `unique_ptr` probably did not fix the issue, but rather just masked it.

Comment: @ATOMP It turns out the problem was the move constructor and move assignment operator (see my comments on the answer below) and Fatih BAKIR also found another bug that caused undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program contains undefined behavior.

The issue is your `fill` resumes the coroutine when `!full_`, regardless of whether the coroutine is at `final suspend` or not, which you can learn by calling `h_.done()`.

```
Generator<uint64_t> Counter(uint64_t i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
    co_yield i;
  }
  // final suspend
}
```

If you resume the coroutine at the final suspend point, it will destory itself and you can no longer do anything with the coroutine handle you have.

And you call `fill` from `operator bool`, meaning that it, when called while the coroutine is suspended at final suspend, first destroys the coroutine, and then tries to access it, which is UB:

```
    fill(); // potentially destroy the coroutine
    return !h_.done(); // access the destroyed coroutine
```

You could fix this by making `fill` aware of `done`ness:

```
   void fill() {
    if (!h_.done() && !full_) {
      h_();
      if (h_.promise().exception_)
        std::rethrow_exception(h_.promise().exception_);
      full_ = true;
    }
  }
```

Also, your move assignment operator leaks the current coroutine:

```
  Generator& operator=(Generator&& g) {
    h_ = std::move(g.h_); // previous h_ is leaked
    g.h_ = nullptr;
    return *this;
  }
```

You probably want to have something like `if (h_) h_.destroy();` in the beginning.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, the `full_` member has to be carried over in the move constructor and assignment operators:

```
Generator(Generator&& g) 
  : h_(std::exchange(g.h_, nullptr))
  , full_(std::exchange(g.full_, false)) {}

Generator& operator=(Generator&& g) {
  full_ = std::exchange(g.full_, false);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried modifying `fill()` as you specified (I see the UB) but I'm still having the issue. I'm going to investigate more though please let me know if there's anything else I overlooked. Thanks!

Comment: One more point/question -- I see the memory leak you mentioned and deliberately left it in for now. I know coroutine handles are essentially pointers that can be held by multiple Generator instances, so I'm debating what the best way is to destroy them, since destroying them in the move constructor and move assignment operator could pull the rug out from under other Generator instances. Perhaps the suggestion you give is the best way, though it feels like I really want to wrap the handles in something like an `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Ahh I figured it out. In my move constructor and move assignment operator, I forgot to move `g.full_` into `full_`. If you update your answer to also include that, I will be happy to accept!

Comment: @JackHumphries, that's great! I was fixated on the `done` stuff I did not even notice that.

Comment: @JackHumphries, sharing the ownership of a coroutine handle sounds dangerous to me, especially if multithreading comes into play. I'd suggest having the main `Generator` type be as limited as possible, and create a `SharedGenerator` around it that explicitly supports sharing.